# I want nesting of transaction in spring boot using @Transactional annotation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-transactions

Currently if exception occurs in method C, code is not rolling back database changes from method B. My expectation is method A should manage transaction in such a way that if exception occurs in method C, code should rollback changes done in method B.
I am using spring boot, maven project.

```java
class SomeClassA{

    @Autowired
    SomeClassB someClassB;

    @Autowired
    SomeClassC someClassC;

    @Transactional
    public A(){
        try{
            //This method works fine with some database operations.
            someClassB.B();

            //In this method, exception occurrs.
            someClassC.C();
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
    }   
}

class SomeClassB{

    @Transactional
    public B(){
        //some code with database operation
    }   
}

class SomeClassC{

    @Transactional
    public C(){
        //some code with database operation
        //some exception occurs here
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a Checked or Runtime exception ?

Because the [default behaviour](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings) of `@Transactional` says:

> Any RuntimeException triggers rollback, and any checked Exception does
>   not.

Comment: It is RuntimeException.

Comment: @AkshayJ But anyway, if the exception is caught in A, I don't think that the rollback for A is triggered, it's only for C.  
Try to remove the try/catch block and see if it rollbacks B too.